# how to run chart in iOS 7 using daniel gindi chart library?

Tags: ios, objective-c, charts

I want to show the chart in iOS 7 using this library https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts. I can able to show a chart using iOS 8 and iOS 9.If i run in iOS 7 means,It shows linker error.Provide me a solution for this.I have done this procedure too.

Procedure which is given in a link:

In order to correctly compile:

1.Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project

2.Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework

3.Temporary workaround: Xcode 6.3.1 has a bug, where you have to build your project once before actually writing the @import line. So hit "Build" now!

4.@import Charts

5.When using Swift in an ObjC project:
You need to import your Bridging Header. Usually it is "YourProject-Swift.h", so in ChartsDemo it's "ChartsDemo-Swift.h". Do not try to actually include "ChartsDemo-Swift.h" in your project :-)

6.Under "Build Options", mark "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code"

If you want to compile for iOS 7:

1. Drag the code itself (.swift files) to your project. As sadly, Swift currently does not support compiling Frameworks for iOS 7.
2. Make sure that the files are added to the Target membership.

Comment: I struck with this error. Please provide me solution for this.I will trying this error from the yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

If i drag my swift code into project and run the app means,it shows error like this:

[Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3PZe.png)